# Is it good practice to derive a builder from the class it builds?

Tags: c++, software-design

Assuming there is a class `Foo`, which shouldn't be changed after construction, but it's difficult to pass everything via constructor, so we want some kind of builder for it. Something like this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    [[nodiscard]] std::vector<std::string> const& getParts() const
    {
        return parts;
    }

private:
    friend class ClassicFooBuilder;
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
};

class ClassicFooBuilder
{
public:
    void addPart(std::string name)
    {
        foo.parts.emplace_back(std::move(name));
    }

    [[nodiscard]] Foo const& result()
    {
        return foo;
    }

private:
    Foo foo;
};

Foo buildFoo()
{
    ClassicFooBuilder builder;
    builder.addPart("head");
    builder.addPart("body");
    builder.addPart("feet");
    return builder.result();
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo = buildFoo();

    for (auto const& part : foo.getParts()) {
        std::cout << part << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't like that I need to specify the `friend` class (and possibly more, if more builders are added later). So I though about deriving the builder like this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    [[nodiscard]] std::vector<std::string> const& getParts() const
    {
        return parts;
    }

protected:
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
};

class DerivedFooBuilder : public Foo
{
public:
    void addPart(std::string name)
    {
        parts.emplace_back(std::move(name));
    }
};

Foo buildFoo()
{
    DerivedFooBuilder builder;
    builder.addPart("head");
    builder.addPart("body");
    builder.addPart("feet");
    return builder;
}
```

This makes use of object slicing, which wouldn't be bad here, I guess, since only the non-const methods are sliced away. The members need to be `protected` instead of `private`, though. Do you think that's a good approach?

Alternatively I could have some `MutableFoo` class derived from a `ConstFoo` class, and make the builder work with a `MutableFoo`, but return a `ConstFoo`, again involving object slicing, to throw away all non-const methods. Would that be cleaner?

Or should I just have a `Foo` class with const and non-const methods, and let the user of the builder make sure the result is `const`?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Comment: No. Why would you do that? The builder doesn't have any business supporting the API of the built item. They are two different things. Don't conflate them.

Comment: I haven't though of that. Any problems with the alternative I mentioned, deriving a "mutable" class from a "const" class and let the builder slice the object to throw away the non-const methods?

Comment: Frankly, "But I don't like that I need to specify the friend" this is a questionalble motivation, and it is unclear how using inheritance instead of friend makes anything better. Why do you not like that you need to specify that the Builder is a friend of the class it builds?

Comment: The builder doesn't really have to slice the object. Just return the *type* of the `const` class, and keep the non-const derivation a secret so nobody can cast it or call its non-const methods. And get over your fixation about `friend`. This kind of thing is exactly what it's for.

Comment: Thank you for all of your input. I realized that my actual problem was naming. What I was calling "builder" really is the non-const part of that class. Deriving a `MutableFoo` from a `ConstFoo` is not so uncommon. That's what I was doing here. The actual builder would be something completely different, `buildFoo()` in my little example, but more complex in reality.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no UB here, which at least guarantees that this code should give the expected result.

The downside is that depending on possible copy elision, you will either create a true `DerivedFooBuilder` in your `main`, or have to build a complete `Foo` subobject inside of the builder to later copy it. And either way is likely to be suboptimal.

Furthermore, `friend` belongs to the language for a reason. And I would call this the *nominal* use case: an auxiliary *thing* needs a access to the private members of another class to allow a better separation of concerns:

- the `Foo` class is responsible for all of the standard behaviour of  the object it models
- as the initialization is complex, you externalize it inside an auxiliary class or function which of course requires access to the private members.

But if the object is really complex and large, I would not use a builder class, but only a builder free function, which could optionaly use an auxiliary class to provide the initialization. That way would allow an optimal use of the copy elisions at creation time.

Comment: Good points, thank you. If the `Foo` class has a move constructor, the cost might be acceptable (especially since there is also a copy made with the classic builder). And I think I cannot use a single free function (it is really more a build process than a simple factory). But I think your answer helped me a lot to find a good solution.